# ¿Cómo hacer que una imagen o icono se adapte al jlabel?

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo un inconveniente, tengo un botón que la función es poder subir una imagen a un jlabel. para entrar en contexto cree un paquete donde coloque una imagen, la función del boton es traer una imagen que seleccione el usuario y esta imagen remplaza la que esta en el paquete de recursos ósea el paquete de la imagen y así funciona.
a paquede de imagen me refiero a esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    private void btnSubirImagenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
    jf.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    if (jf.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG) {
        rsdragdropfiles.RSDragDropFiles.setCopiar(jf.getSelectedFile().toString(), "src/img/usuario.png");
        lbImagen.setIcon(new ImageIcon(jf.getSelectedFile().toString()));
    }
}
```

este es el código que utilice, y como les comento si coloco una imagen muy grande esta no se ajusta al jlabel que es como del tamaño de una foto de carnet y no se como hacer eso, agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya la resolví, debemos descargar la librería RSScaleLabel
luego solo le cambio como envió la imagen al jlabel

```
    private void btnSubirImagenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
jf.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
if (jf.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG) {
    rsdragdropfiles.RSDragDropFiles.setCopiar(jf.getSelectedFile().toString(), "src/img/usuario.png");
   rsscalelabel.RSScaleLabel.setScaleLabel(lbImagen,  "src/img/usuario.png"); 
}
```

}
y así queda y listo